# Simple jQuery Mobile / AJAX login

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, filemaker, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm tasked with building a user-login-capable mobile app and using PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile, AJAX, and PHP to do it. I'm trying to start somewhat simply and build on a basic HTML and PHP structure, since I'm not a programmer and don't have much experience in this stuff. But even my simple user login form isn't working properly.

I have the following HTML code that will serve as the user login page (sampleindex.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/P32-Manager.css">   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/jQuery-Overrides.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
function userLogin(email) {
    if (email == "") {
        document.getElementById("logincontainer").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("logincontainer").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","samplehome.php?UserName="+email,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="logincontainer">

    <form action="sampleindex.html" method="get">

        <div style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;">

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="text-align:center; position:relative; top:0em; left:0.5em; width:100%; margin:auto; border:0;">
                <label for="username" style="display:block; width:350px; text-align:left;">Username (Email)
                <input data-clear-btn="false" name="UserName" type="text" value="" class="ui-input-text" style="height:40px; font-size:18px;">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="text-align:center; position:relative; top:-1.25em; left:0.5em; width:100%; margin:auto; border:0;">
                <label for="password" style="display:block; width:350px; text-align:left;">Password
                <input data-clear-btn="false" name="Password" type="password" value="" class="ui-input-text" autocomplete="off" style="height:40px; font-size:18px;">
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="text-align:center; position:relative; top:-0.5em; left:-1em; width:100%; margin:auto; border:0;">
            <div id="login-button" style="position:relative; left:0em; width:300px; height:62px; margin:auto; border:0; background-color:#ffffff;" data-inline="true">
                <input data-role="button" name="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Login" style="position:absolute; left:0em;" onClick="userLogin(UserName);">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>         

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

We're using FileMaker (don't let that scare you -- it's similar enough to MySQL that programmers should be able to understand what's going on) for our database and the FileMaker PHP API to connect that database to the mobile app. The database is connected through the "included" dbaccess.php file (not shown here), and the layout used is called "Demo php". The first value I want to pass in my URL, an email address format, is called "UserName" and corresponds with the database column called "UserName." I would like to $_GET that UserName from the URL and then return the corresponding "FirstName." Beyond that, I will want to get the RecordID from the database row that corresponds to the submitted query, so I can serve each logged-in user their specific information. (Not too worried about security yet, as I'm just trying to show a proof of concept, hence the "get" in the form.)

Here's my PHP file (samplehome.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged-in']=0;
?>

<?php 

include ("../../dbaccess.php"); 

$username = urldecode($_GET['UserName']);

if(isset($_GET['loginbutton']) and (!empty($_GET['UserName']) and !empty($_GET['Password'])) )
{
$username = '==' . urldecode($_GET['UserName']);
$password = md5($_GET['Password']);
$request = $fm->newFindCommand('Demo php');
$request->addFindCriterion('UserName', $username);
$request->addFindCriterion('Password', $password);
$result = $request->execute();

if (FileMaker::isError($result)) 
    {
    $request = $fm->newFindAllCommand('Demo php');
    $result = $request->execute();
    }

$found = $result->getFoundSetCount();

$records = $result->getRecords();

if($found == 1)
    {
    $_SESSION['logged-in']=1;

    echo '<table border="1">
              <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
              </tr>';

    foreach ($records as $record)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $record->getField('FirstName') . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';

    }

else
    {
    $_SESSION['logged-in']=0;

    echo 'nope';
    }

}   

?>
```

Currently, nothing is returned when I click "Login," just a blank page with the background color of my jQuery theme. (This blank result also occurs when I don't use the jQuery stylesheets and scripts.) The URL doesn't have anything passed in it, despite my use of "get." Which I assume is because of my use of jQuery and AJAX. Anyone know what's wrong (and also, how I would be able to use passed ID values such as "UserName" despite the page not refreshing with AJAX/jQuery)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't referencing the entered value correctly.

```
 onClick="userLogin(UserName);"
```

here you have UserName, but in this context, UserName is a javascript variable, which is undefined as far as I can tell.

In your userLogin function, the first thing you do is:

```
function userLogin(email) {
    if (email == "") {
        document.getElementById("logincontainer").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
```

in this case, email is undefined (because UserName was undefined) and javascript compares undefined to "", which is true, and blanks out your page.

You need to either pass in the value of the UserName input or get the value from your function.

first, assign an id to your username input:

```
<input data-clear-btn="false" name="UserName" type="text" value="" class="ui-input-text" style="height:40px; font-size:18px;" id="UserName">
```

then, change your onclick:

```
 onClick="userLogin(document.getElementById('UserName').value);"
```

that should get you past the initial html blanking.  I don't know what will happen after that.

You might also want to replace the html blanking with an alert or something so that you don't have to reload the page if the username field was blank.

Comment: Mark, thanks. I wasn't able to get it to work, though. I'm still getting a blank page after adding the id to the UserName input and the revised onClick line. When clicking the Login button even without anything filled in to the text fields, the resulting page loads blank as well. By the way, does it matter what I call the UserName field in the URL? I just used that particular capitalization because that's what the field's column was in the sample database. I don't know that I have a fundamental understanding of what gets passed and what's just a name.

Comment: Ok, I made a JS Fiddle that hopefully will get you a little further.  https://jsfiddle.net/xh6651my/  I put an id on your form and your field.  I changed your function to a general vaildate function.  I reference the inputs from the function rather than passing in values.  I converted your ajax and element references to jquery notation since you already are including it on the page.  I hope this helps.  You can name your variables whatever you want on the url, you just have to match what your php page is looking for.  Note the fiddle isn't fully functional since i don't have the target pages.